# Snowflake Python Okta Connection

Tags: python, pycharm, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, okta

I am trying python connection to snowflake using snowflake.connector library along with OKTA authentication. I am using the following code to execute but getting error:

```
Failed to execute request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url
```

**Code I am using**

```
username = username for okta
authenticator = 'https://companyname.okta.com'
account_name = 'https://xy12345.us-east-2.snowflakecomputing.com/'
warehouse = ''
password = password for okta

conn = sf.connect(user = username, authenticator = authenticator, account = account_name, password = password)
```

Anyone has an idea to make it work?

Comment: is your problem got resolved

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me `authenticator='externalbrowser',`

```html
snowflake_connection = snowflake.connector.connect(
    authenticator='externalbrowser',
    user=<SNOWFLAKE_USER>,
    account=<SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT>,
    database=<SNOWFLAKE_DB>,
    schema=<SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA>,
    warehouse=<SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your account_name is correct.  It should be in the form of '<your_account_name>.<region_id>.' (e.g. 'xy12345.east-us-2.azure').  Using the URL you have in your example, it'd simply be `location`.

Comment: the above one is for reference. In actual my account_name is like 'https://xy12345.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com'. let me know if that's incorrect. I will edit my post to display it correctly.

Comment: Just take off the `.snowflakecomputing.com` piece, and you've got it.